# LNK 2028 - 2019 / Managed and Unmanaged C++ ? (VS 2008)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, unmanaged, lnk2019, tetgen

I am trying to link an open-source library to one of my project. The library is unmanaged (named Tetgen) and my project is in managed C++.

My project recognizes the header and can use the functions defined in it.  But I get a 2028 error each time it wants to access to some methods defined in the .cpp:

> error LNK2028: unresolved token (0A000E20) "public: void __thiscall tetgenio::save_nodes(char const *)" (?save_nodes@tetgenio@@$$FQAEXPBD@Z) referenced in function "public: virtual bool __thiscall ForwardModelingPlugin::CustomMeshVol3D::tesselate(void)" (?tesselate@CustomMeshVol3D@ForwardModelingPlugin@@$$FUAE_NXZ)

I have tried to create a test function:

```
int tetgenio::Test(int i) {  
    return i;  
}
```

...and another Testbis function, defined in the header. Testbis works, Test gives a 2028 error.

I have compared the .obj of my project and the .lib created, and for the lib there is:

```
save_nodes@tetgenio@@QAEXPAD@Z
```

But in the .obj it is:

```
save_nodes@tetgenio@@$$FQAEXPBD@Z in the .obj
```

It appears they are not the same.

Everything is compiled with /clr.  I've tried creating both a .lib and a .dll, with same results either way.

Comment: Is Tetgen itself compiled with /clr? If not, it needs to be.

Comment: Yes it is. Everything is compiled in /clr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That was because of a linker problem linking to different folders containing the same files.